# Can I get user line separator on web?

Tags: web-services, character-encoding

I wanna create csv download service on web.
Is there any way to get line separator for user OS ?

I'm using Java for server programming.
And there are some way to get line separator, but they are depend on server OS,
not user :<

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, *you're* the server in this case so, unless the user tells you what their line ending is with their request, you won't know.

Probably the simplest solution is to allow the user to select manually, with a drop-down box, then use that information to generate the format you want.